# How to fix Access Violation Reading location error?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hashtable

I am currently working on a program that uses a Hash table. I have worked on my own Hash table class and the program works but then crashes after it has already done the work involving the hash table. The error I get is a Access Violation reading location error. I have spent hours going through my code and still cannot find what I'm doing wrong or why the program is crashing. Here are my problem classes below:

Hashtable.h:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H

#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class hashTable
{
    public:

        hashTable();
        virtual ~hashTable();
        void insertNode(string nodeData);
        bool removeNode(string nodeKey);
          Node * checkForDuplicate( string nodeData );

    private:
        LinkedList * tableArray;
        int length;
        int hash(string stateKey);

};

#endif // HASHTABLE_H
```

Hashtable.cpp:

```
#include "hashTable.h"


hashTable::hashTable()
{
   length = 181667;
   tableArray = new LinkedList[length];

}

int hashTable::hash(string stateKey) {

    int multiplier = 1;
    int total = 0;
    int l = stateKey.length();
    for(int i = l - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        int temp;
        temp = (stateKey[i] - '0') * multiplier;
        total += temp;
        multiplier = multiplier * 10;
    }
    return(total) % length;
}

void hashTable::insertNode(string stateData) {

    Node * newNode;
    newNode = new Node;

    newNode->data = stateData;

    int index = hash(newNode -> data);

    tableArray[index].insertNode(newNode);

    delete newNode;

}

bool hashTable::removeNode(string nodeKey) {

    int index = hash(nodeKey);
    return tableArray[index].removeNode(nodeKey);

}

Node * hashTable::checkForDuplicate( string nodeData )
{
    int index = hash( nodeData );

    return tableArray[ index ].getNode(nodeData);   
}


hashTable::~hashTable()
{
    delete [] tableArray;
    //dtor
}
```

LinkedList.h:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string data;
    Node *next;

};

class LinkedList
{
    public:
        LinkedList();
        void insertNode(Node * newNode);
        bool removeNode(string stateData);
        Node * getNode(string stateData);
        int getLength();

        virtual ~LinkedList();

    private:
        Node * top;
        int length;
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    top = new Node;
    top->next = NULL;
    length = 0;

}

void LinkedList :: insertNode(Node * newNode) {

    Node * a = top;
    Node * b = top;

    while(b) {

        a = b;
        b = a -> next;

        if (a== NULL) { break; }
    }

    a -> next = newNode;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    length++;
 }


bool LinkedList :: removeNode(string stateData) {

    if(!top -> next){
        return false;
    }
    Node * a = top;
    Node * b = top;

    while(b) {
        if(b->data == stateData) {
            a->next = b->next;
            delete b;
            length--;
            return true;
        }
        a = b;
        b = a ->next;
    }
    return false;
}

Node * LinkedList :: getNode(string stateData) {

    if(top == NULL) { return NULL ;}

    Node * current = top;

    while (current->next != NULL) {

        if((current->data == stateData)) {
            return current;
        }
        current = current -> next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int LinkedList :: getLength() {

    return length;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node * a = top;
    Node * b = top;
    while (b) {
        a = b;
        b = a->next;
        if(b) delete a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you have virtual destructors for classes without any virtual functions?

Comment: I based my classes on classes I found on-line and they had the virtual destructor's already so I used them.

Comment: Please reduce this code to a [mcve].

Comment: *"I based my classes on classes I found on-line and they had the virtual destructor's already so I used them."* That is a *really* bad idea, learning C++ by trial and error will get you nowhere. You should learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: You are correct. I already learned about the concepts using linked lists and hash tables so I thought I would be able change the classes I used to suit my application. Next time I shall use a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hashTable::insertNode()` method is allocating a new `Node` object, then passing it to `LinkedList::insertNode()` to **take ownership** of the object, but then **`delete`'s it** afterwards, thus leaving the `LinkedList` with a dangling pointer to invalid memory.  Any access to that node will cause undefined behavior.  DO NOT `delete` the new node after `LinkedList` takes ownership of it.

It would be better if `LinkedList::insertNode()` took a `string` as input instead of a `Node*` pointer.  Let `LinkedList` allocate the new node internally.

Also, there are some other minor issues with your `LinkedList()` implementation in general (like not following the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and not using a double-linked list for more efficient inserts and removals).

Try something more like this instead:

Hashtable.h:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H

#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"

class hashTable
{
public:
    hashTable();
    hashTable(const hashTable &src);
    ~hashTable();

    void insertNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    bool removeNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    bool checkForDuplicate(const std::string &nodeData);

    hashTable& operator=(const hashTable &rhs);

private:
    std::vector<LinkedList> tableArray;
    int length;

    int hash(const std::string &nodeData);
};

#endif // HASHTABLE_H
```

Hashtable.cpp:

```
#include "hashTable.h"

hashTable::hashTable()
   : length(181667), tableArray(new LinkedList[length])
{
}

hashTable::hashTable(const hashTable &src)
    : length(src.length), tableArray(new LinkedList[length])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        tableArray[i] = src.tableArray[i];
}

hashTable::~hashTable()
{
    delete[] tableArray;
}

hashTable& hashTable::operator=(const hashTable &rhs)
{
    hashTable tmp(rhs);
    std::swap(tableArray, tmp.tableArray);
    std::swap(length, tmp.length);
    return *this;
}

int hashTable::hash(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int multiplier = 1;
    int total = 0;
    int l = nodeData.length();
    for(int i = l - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        int temp = (nodeData[i] - '0') * multiplier;
        total += temp;
        multiplier *= 10;
    }
    return total % length;
}

void hashTable::insertNode(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    tableArray[index].insertNode(nodeData);
}

bool hashTable::removeNode(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    return tableArray[index].removeNode(nodeData);
}

bool hashTable::checkForDuplicate(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    return (tableArray[index].getNode(nodeData) != NULL);
}
```

LinkedList.h:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <string>

struct Node
{
    std::string data;
    Node *previous;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &src);
    ~LinkedList();

    void insertNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    bool removeNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    Node* getNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    int getLength();

    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &rhs);

private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int length;
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#inclue <algorithm>

LinkedList::LinkedList()
    : head(NULL), tail(NULL), length(0)
{
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList &src)
    : head(NULL), tail(NULL), length(0)
{
    Node *current = src.top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        insertNode(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *current = top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        Node *next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}

LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList &rhs)
{
    LinkedList tmp;

    Node *current = rhs.top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        tmp.insertNode(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    std::swap(top, tmp.top);
    std::swap(bottom, tmp.bottom);
    std::swap(length, tmp.length);

    return *this;
}

void LinkedList::insertNode(const string &nodeData)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;    
    newNode->data = nodeData;
    newNode->previous = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (top == NULL) top = newNode;
    if (bottom != NULL)
    {
        newNode->previous = bottom;
        bottom->next = newNode;
    }
    bottom = newNode;

    length++;
 }

bool LinkedList::removeNode(const string &nodeData)
{
    Node* node = getNode(nodeData);
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->next != NULL)
            node->next->previous = node->previous;
        if (node->previous != NULL)
            node->previous->next = node->next;
        if (top == node)
            top = node->next;
        if (bottom == node)
            bottom = node->previous;

        delete node;
        length--;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

Node* LinkedList::getNode(const string &nodeData)
{
    Node *current = top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->data == nodeData)
            return current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int LinkedList::getLength()
{
    return length;
}
```

With that said, you can then get rid of `LinkedList` altogether by using `std::list` instead, and simplify `hashTable`'s memory management by using `std::vector`:

Hashtable.h:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class hashTable
{
public:
    hashTable();

    void insertNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    bool removeNode(const std::string &nodeData);
    bool checkForDuplicate(const std::string &nodeData);

private:
    std::vector< std::list<std::string> > tableArray;

    int hash(const std::string &stateKey);
};

#endif // HASHTABLE_H
```

Hashtable.cpp:

```
#include "hashTable.h"
#include <algorithm>

hashTable::hashTable()
   : tableArray(181667)
{
}

int hashTable::hash(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int multiplier = 1;
    int total = 0;
    int l = nodeData.length();
    for(int i = l - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        int temp = (nodeData[i] - '0') * multiplier;
        total += temp;
        multiplier *= 10;
    }
    return total % length;
}

void hashTable::insertNode(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    tableArray[index].push_back(nodeData);
}

bool hashTable::removeNode(const string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    std::list<std::string>::iterator iter = std::find(tableArray[index].begin(), tableArray[index].end(), nodeData);
    if (iter != tableArray[index].end())
    {
        tableArray[index].erase(iter);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool hashTable::checkForDuplicate(const std::string &nodeData)
{
    int index = hash(nodeData);
    std::list<std::string>::iterator iter = std::find(tableArray[index].begin(), tableArray[index].end(), nodeData);
    return (iter != tableArray[index].end());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that this has solved my issue.